# Type of Variable not as expected in Powershell

Tags: powershell, variable-assignment, powershell-5.0

This is a question of understanding.

I construct a Directory Structure using a string Variable `$path`. I append the name of the Directory I want to create, this works as expected. When the path is completed I need the complete Directory as `System.IO.DirectoryInfo` but assigning the Path in this way `$Path = Get-Item $Path` results in a string type.

```
$path = "c:\dir1"
If(-Not (Test-Path $path))New-Item -ItemType Directory -Path $path
$path = $path + "\dir2"
If(-Not (Test-Path $path))New-Item -ItemType Directory -Path $path

# Assigned to same variable
$path = Get-Item $path
echo $path.GetType() # = string

# assigned to different variable
$p_a_t_h = Get-Item $path
echo $p_a_t_h.GetType() # = System.IO.DirectoryInfo

# solution but not understood the behavior
[System.IO.DirectoryInfo]$path = Get-Item $path
echo $path.GetType() # = System.IO.DirectoryInfo
```

It took hours to find out this behavior and I couldn't find any documentation why this is - maybe because I don't know what to search for.

It is clear, that for appending something to a variable, the type of the variable is relevant, but a `$path = ...` is a "new" assignement and should have the type of the assigned value - at least in my eyes. In the languages I used so far a variable becomes the type of its value and is not converted to a type the variable had earlier or I define the type of a variable and get an error if assigned with wrong type.

Where is the error in my logic?

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/new-item?view=powershell-5.1

The Path parameter accepts a string input not a System.IO.DirecetoryInfo object

Comment: Why do you need/want to reassign the same variable when using separate variables (of the type you require) would make your life much easier?

Comment: @James it is not too important to have the same variable reassigned - for me it is just the same information with a different tpye. It is just a little script and i didn't think too much about it until i came across this problem. The point is not to solve the problem - i did already in many ways, but to understand why this is the case.

Comment: @user2734259 i know this and that's the reason why i tried to reassign `[System.IO.DirectoryInfo]$path` after i have created the Directorystructure using `[string]$path`

Comment: @user2734259 I've changed my script according to the info from briantist and found out that the `-Path` parameter accepts a `[System.IO.DirecetoryInfo]` object - no need to use `[System.IO.DirecetoryInfo]$path.FullName`

Comment: Nice, that's great to know! Haven't had that need before I don't think but can see that being very handy. Thanks for sharing

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think that somewhere in your code you did a left-side cast (on the variable, not the value) to `[String]`, just like you did later in your sample with `[System.IO.DirectoryInfo]$path`.

The most common way that this happens: Parameters.

Is this taken from a function? Like:

```
function Invoke-MyThing {
param([String]$Path)

}
```

---

### Why that matters

When you put the type on the variable, all values assigned to that variable receive that cast.

```
[String]$Value = 'Hello'
$Value.GetType()

$Value = 3.141
$Value.GetType()
```

Casting the value only affects that one value:

```
$V2 = 5
$V2.GetType()

$V2 = [String]9
$V2.GetType()

$V2 = 45
$V2.GetType()
```

So, remove your previous variable-side cast, or if it's a parameter, just use a different local variable.

Better yet, if it's a parameter, you could make it of type `[System.IO.DirectoryInfo]` instead.. then it would accept that directly, or even accept a string. You just have to rework your code a little bit to deal with it.

Comment: Yes it was a parameter. Do i understand this correctly, if i don't cast the variable anywhere it will be of the type of the value i assigned and will change when reassigned?
When i use `[System.IO.DirectoryInfo]` and assign a `[string]` to it, can i still append/reassign a new `[string]` or do i need the `-Name` or `-FullName` Attributes?
`$path.name = $path.name + "\somedit"` or
`$path = $path.name + "\somedir"`

Comment: @HolgerZ if the variable has no cast assigned, you can reassign new values of new types and it will accept those types. If the variable has a cast, that cast will apply to the value on assignment (following all the same rules of any cast).